# How to make Jenkinsfile credential visible to many stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkinsfile

In Jenkinsfile, I want to make an `ssh key` visible to all stages in the pipeline.

From the official document, I learned that:

1. `environment` directive is used to defy environment variables for used within Jenkinsfile
2. The scope of the variables defined depends on the placement of the `environment` directive
3. One can set the **some types of credentials** inside`environment` directive with the help of the `credentials` helper
4. The types of credentials supported by the helper are:

   - Secret text
   - Usernames and passwords
   - Secret files

For other types of credentials, the document suggests using the `snippet generator`, which generates a step.

Example of an ssh key step

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'jenkins_aws_to_bitbucket', keyFileVariable: 'BITBUCKET_PRV_KEY')]) {
    // some block
}
```

This is meant to be used in a *stage* like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        // define agent details
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example stage 1') {
            steps {
                withCredentials(bindings: [sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'jenkins-ssh-key-for-abc', \
                                                             keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY_FOR_ABC')]) {
                  // 
                }
                withCredentials(bindings: [certificate(credentialsId: 'jenkins-certificate-for-xyz', \
                                                       keystoreVariable: 'CERTIFICATE_FOR_XYZ', \
                                                       passwordVariable: 'XYZ-CERTIFICATE-PASSWORD')]) {
                  // 
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Example stage 2') {
            steps {
                // 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[*Snippet source*](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)

**Question**

1. If the steps are within a *stage*, are these credentials visible within other stages?
2. If not, how to make these credentials *global* ~ visible within all stages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The credentials will only be visible within the block passed to `withCredentials`, not outside of that.  So, no, your credentials will not be visible to other stages.  To make your credentials visible to your entire Pipeline:

- If you are using Declarative Pipelines, you can put your credentials in an `environment{}` block at the top of your Pipeline, as documented in the [official Jenkins handbook](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials):

  ```
  pipeline {
      agent {
          // Your agent here
      }
      environment {
          MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = credentials('my-credentials-id')
      }
      stages {
          // Your stages here
      }
  }
  ```
- If you use Scripted Pipelines, you can wrap your entire job in `withCredentials`.  This is not possible with Declarative.

Comment: Number 2 might have been correct at the time the answer was posted, but it absolutely is not correct at the time of this comment.
An `environment{}` block with the `credentials()` method provides an implicit global `withCredentials`

Comment: @KenRachynski I looked it up, and support for `credentials` in the `environment{}` block was added in April 2017, which is before I wrote this answer, but it seems to have been poorly documented at the time, especially compared to the `withCredentials` step which well predates Jenkins Pipelines.  I'm editing my answer to improve its accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

I set credential globally in declarative pipeline like this and then my Jenkins could talk with Google Dataflow in all stages.  For example, I used a secret file (google service account).

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        //Secret File ID was defined in Jenkins -> Credentials -> System -> Global credentials
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = credentials('mySecretFileId')

        GCP_PROJECT_NAME = 'myProject'
    }
   stages {
             stage('step 1') {
              steps {
                sh "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}"
                sh "gcloud config set project ${env.GCP_PROJECT_NAME}"

                // access google dataflow
                sh "gcloud dataflow jobs list --status=active"
                // ....
              }
             }
             stage('stage 2') {
               steps {
                  // access google dataflow
                  sh "gcloud dataflow jobs list --status=active"
               }
             }
             //...
   }
}
```

Comment: Best answer for this question.